# how to download a generated pdf file using playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I'm trying to download a file using playwright, this file is generated which means the url doesn't ends with a '.pdf' and forcing this link in the url doesn't start the download. I was abble to navigate until the pdf is generated but how can I download it now ?

here is my code:

```js
const {chromium} = require('playwright');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext({
        acceptDownloads: true
    });
    const page = await context.newPage();

    const downloadPath = path.join(__dirname, 'edt');

    await page.goto('https://planif.eppe.ui/jsp/custom/eppee/easyMyPlanning.jsp');
    await page.getByLabel('Identifiant :').click();
    await page.getByLabel('Identifiant :').fill('myusername');
    await page.getByLabel('Identifiant :').press('Tab');
    await page.getByLabel('Mot de passe :').fill('mysecretpassword');
    await page.getByLabel('Mot de passe :').press('Enter');
    await page.getByRole('combobox').selectOption('10');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click();
    await page.locator('.footer > a').click();
    const page1Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
    await page.frameLocator('frame[name="link"]').getByRole('link', { name: 'Export PDF...' }).click();
    const page1 = await page1Promise;
    const downloadPromise = page1.waitForEvent('download');
    await page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click();
    const download = await downloadPromise;
    await download.saveAs(path.join(downloadPath, 'edt.pdf'));
    await browser.close();
})();
```

with this code I end up having the browser waiting for me to try to download the file how can I automate this ?

ps: with this code and with my browser in non headless mode I end up on this page end if I manualy press the download button it works
[image]

Comment: try "const fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFileSync('saved.pdf', await page1.content());"